# Cache control and Meta cache control

Tags: caching, controls, meta

Question about how browsers understand cache control and meta cache control tags

If i have something like this:

Cache-control: no-cache, no-store

and later i have

< meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, s-maxage=0" />

Which cache control is applied to the page? Does it work in the same way in all the browsers?

Thanks